# Compression or Decompression

Tags: archive, compression

My question is that if I have two files suppose :

file_1.gz and file_2.gz

then can I compress these to files into another compressed file ex file_1+2.gz (Just a name.)

The catch is that I dont want it to be decompressed first, just direct concatenate the contents to a single file.

Any views?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tar cvf my-uncompressed-archive.tar *.gz` to do that .

Comment: Will it give me the output also in the ".gz" format @Frantique ??

Comment: No, it will be tar archive. Can you explain why you need gz, if you don't want to compress it?

Comment: That is the one and proper Un*x solution, +1 for that.

Comment: It would give you a tar-file (an archive).  Sure you could gzip the archive - even get tar to do it - but that would be rather pointless, as the two files the archive contains are already compressed.  Compressing something that's already compressed, is actually likely to cause you to end-up with a larger file than the uncompressed one.

Answer (score 0):

gzip deflate compression algorithm includes an encoding that is build along the compression. These two files have different encoding you cannot concatenate them into one file without uncompressing them before. The result would have no meaning.

Here is method to concatenate, it uses decompression but avoid intermediary files.

```
zcat file1.gz file2.gz | gzip > file3.gz
```

Another method suggested by Frantique is  put your files into one archive (but it is not concatenation, it is stacking)